# PHP realtime notifications (pusher?)

Tags: php, codeigniter, real-time, pusher

Say I had an app where customers can make a type of booking, and then I had an admin interface  to manage these incoming customer bookings.

How would I allow new bookings to be pushed to the admin interface without refreshing. Similar to how Facebook push new notifications to you.

I looked at AJAX however, from what I understand this only works by calling the data, which can be done by setting an interval like every 5 seconds. This seems un-ideal as even when no new data is available the function will run, wasting bandwidth, and risking performance.

What I am looking for is a way for the server to pass booking data over to the admin interface every-time, a customer makes a new booking.

I have looked at an app called pusher, but I dont really know how this would work with something like PHP -codeinigter, and how to implement it?

Does anyone have any information on this kind of system im talking about

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to look into something like [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/), or [Pusher-PHP](https://github.com/squeeks/Pusher-PHP)

Comment: You can easily use Node.js to create real-time apps in PHP. [source](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/chat-app-with-php-nodejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://pusher.com/ , I have also been looking into realtime updates recently and one apparent solution is 'Reverse Ajax'.

This involves as another user mentioned a form of long polling, keeping a connection open to a server and data being passed directly.

Pusher provides several backend libraries in a wide range of languages and a javascript interface to pass json strings to the user.

If you are interested running this internally without using a service such as pusher have a look at http://www.ape-project.org/ for setting up your own push server (based on Comet Server)

I wont say much more as the links above explains it far more elegantly!

Comment: The Pusher client for PHP is old and needs updating. It has not worked since Nov 2013. As of Apr 2014 Pusher still links to the broken PHP client. It took Pusher support 3 days to confirm for me that the client was broken and they weren't going to support it. You could accomplish this via Gearman or Beanstalk depending on the design of the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at html5 "Websockets" or "Long polling"(will work with old browsers).

Answer (score 0):

i would not break my head with trying to get fancy here.

i recommend if bandwitdh is an issue, to have a secondary page that sends back timestamp. and your admin interface checks the timestamp every 5 seconds, if time stamp has changed then it request with ajax once again the changes or the new data to replace.  the bandwidth is unnoticeable with such a tiny request. btw fb does a simple ajax poll also every few seconds.